# Multitouch Gestures - Maverick -> Natty upgrade

Tags: 11.04, multi-touch, lenovo, gestures

I'm using a Lenovo T410. I upgraded from Maverick to Natty. utouch didn't get installed, so I installed it with aptitude.

The only gesture I have working is two finger scrolling, which was active prior to installing utouch. None of the other gestures do anything.

What am I missing? I'm pretty sure the laptop supports multitouch.

Comment: Do you use a synaptics touchpad? It doesn't support any gestures other than two finger scrolling yet. Expect stuff to change in 11.10.

Comment: Yeah, its a synaptics. Is that a software limitation, then?

Answer (score 1):

As you said in your comment, you use a Synaptics touchpad. I also had a similar experience; I bought a new shiny laptop with a Synaptics multitouch touchpad and was excited on using gestures in Ubuntu. The problem is that the Synaptics touchpad driver in Ubuntu doesn't support any advanced gestures other than two finger scrolling.

Work is going on to improve MT (multitouch) support for Synaptics touchpads, and we may get better support in 11.10 (not confirmed, but I hope so). Even if full support is implemented, one thing to note is that the Synaptics touchpads don't support finger presses above 3 fingers, and it also doesn't support rotating gestures (though zoom, drag, 3-finger press/drag, etc are supported). That's a hardware limitation, and nothing much can be done about that.